Using a backslash for an imap_user for mutt to send an email from terminal
I am trying to send an email from a shell script, and I am using mutt with sendmail. The imap_user has a backslash in the user name, and I have not been able to create the variable such that the backslash is included. The documentation appears to say that I can use another backslash as an escape key, but that is not working. The following are things I have tried and their corresponding output:
set imap_user = "domain\user
The output for this was imap_user="domainuser"
set imap_user = "domain\\user
The output for this was imap_user="domain\\user"
set imap_user = "domain"\\"user
The output for this was imap_user="domain\\user"
set imap_user = "domain"\"user
The output for this was imap_user="domain\"user"
set imap_user = 'domain\user'
The output for this was imap_user="domain\\user"
I also tried creating a global variable called backslash and using that in the command, but that didn't work either. Any ideas on how I can put a backslash in the imap_user variable properly?

You have tagged bash.
The syntax set variable = value isn't bash syntax.  Use variable=value or export variable=value instead
